# SYBASE Database Sybase.AdoNet4.AseClient.dll Microsoft ASP .NET C# 4.0

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, dll, sybase

I'm working at asp.net c# web application using sybase database. 
And for data access layer I'm using Sybase.AdoNet4.AseClient.dll 
 
By using this dll ; I can call stored procedures easily.
Let's suppose sp like

> [SELECT AMOUNT FROM TABLE_ABC](Note AMOUNT datatype NUMERIC(20,6))

when I call this stored procedure, my C# code not able to handle NUMERIC value. 
Here is my C# Code.

```cs
AseCommand cmd = new AseCommand("{ ? = call GETAmount ()}", con);
AseParameter return_amount = new AseParameter(0, AseDbType.Numeric, 20);
return_amount.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
return_amount.Precision = 9;
cmd.Parameters.Add(return_amount);
```

**Anyone please help how to set

> NUMERIC(20,6)

in C# with using data access layer library Sybase.AdoNet4.AseClient.dll** 
[image]

Comment: Finally solution I got the solution to fix numeric's decimal point values.

[link](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc20066.1570100/doc/html/san1364409603806.html)

Answer (score 0):

**SYBASE NUMERIC(20,6) will use in ASP.NET C# as given below**

```
AseParameter return_amount = new AseParameter(0, AseDbType.Numeric, 20);
return_amount.Direction = ParameterDirection.ReturnValue;
return_amount.Precision = 20;
return_amount.Scale = 6;
cmd.Parameters.Add(return_amount);
```

further more learning and understanding follow this link 
[link description here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc20066.1570100/doc/html/san1364409603431.html)